# Create MySQL event that executes first Sunday of every month

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

How do you create a MySQL scheduled event that executes the first Sunday of each month?

Answer (score 2):

Write an EVENT that runs every Sunday.  Have it check to see if it is the first Sunday (day of month <= 7).  WHen that test fails, do nothing.

Comment: Interesting way of going about it, I guess this would be the only way to get around it if they do not support it OoB.

Comment: Sometimes it is best to "think out of the box".